# Grails 2.4.4: services does not inject: integration test

Tags: grails, integration-testing, spock

I have service with dependency service like:

```
class ParserService {
    def depService;

    private def parseLine(lineParts) {
    ...
    def set = depService.findItemByName(tmpModule.name);//depService == null
    ...
```

I try to implement integration test like:

```
@TestFor(ParserService)
class ParserServiceTest extends IntegrationSpec {
    def "should not parse comment"() {
        when:
        ...
        def resultList = service.parseAnnotations(inputStream);
```

resources.groovy:

```
beans = {
}
```

And I have NullPointerException: depService - null

Comment: Do you have a service called DepService? make sure your spelling is correct

Comment: I have depService. I can run application(not test) - and all works fine.

Comment: Also try to post more code, how are you calling the service(using the service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@TestFor` annotation is only for unit tests. The integration tests work like a normal beans, so Grails/Spring will inject your dependencies in your tests if you define the services as properties in your class, like in a controller/service/domain class.

Answer (score 1):

Your test case should extend the class `GroovyTestCase` or `IntegrationSpec` and that's pretty much it. Of course the dependency injection then works the usual way

```
class ParserServiceTest extends IntegrationSpec {
   ParserService parserService

   def "should not parse comment"() {
    when:
    ...
    def resultList = parserService.parseAnnotations(inputStream)
...
```